# Application.Quit command not closing the entire Excel Application

Tags: excel, vba

I have following code under a button. When clicked it just closes the current Excel sheet but not the entire Excel application.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Quit
```

**Note:** I don't have any other sheets open.

The following window still appears.

[image]

Comment: Could you have more than one Excel application open at the same time??

Comment: No., i dont have any other sheets open

Comment: You could have workbooks open in the background (not visible).

Comment: anything in the `Workbook_BeforeClose()` event?

Comment: check task manager for other instances of excel.

Comment: Excel 2010? When I run this code it closes the application (but prompts to save any unsaved workbooks).

Comment: Do you use the Personal workbook to store macros, or have addins?

Comment: It is Excel 2010, i am storing macros in personal workbook & there is no beforeclose() event. Also there is no other excel running in background. i have checked task manager.

Comment: for people who are searching the same thing, but through using COM automation objects, there is an issue with how immediately these objects are being released - excel instance will not terminate unless all COM objects have been released, and especially in case of Java garbage collection, you can never be sure when exactly this is going to happen, even though you may release these objects in code. for java and JACOB fans : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980483/jacob-doesnt-release-the-objects-properly#1448272

Comment: I have encountered this same issue. I open an XLAM, have it programmatically open 6 .xlsx files, and when closing the application, it closes the .xlsx files, but I am left with Excel open without any workbooks, and 3 VBAProjects open for files that are already closed.
I was able to reduce the number of leftover VBAProjects by setting WorkBook objects = nothing.
Excel refuses to close, whether by clicking the X in the upper right, issuing Application.Quit File/Close is greyed out. I have read this could relate to issues with add-ins, but I have already removed all add-ins that are absolutely ne

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue and I resolved it by putting in the `Workbook_BeforeClose()`:

```
ThisWorkbook.saved = true
```

Comment: This is more than likely the answer, because it sounds like you have a dialog that isn't being dealt with and is therefore preventing the application from quitting. This will prevent a save dialog from appearing during the workbook closing.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same issue and was able to resolve the issue with code that looks to see if multiple workbooks are open or not ...

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If Application.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then  'Close Excel application
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.Quit
Else                                     'Close the active workbook
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .Close Savechanges:=True
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Thank you i was having the same problem and solved it with this code

Answer (score 4):

When Application.Quit is encountered in a subroutine,
it will only stay in memory and continue to run lines under it
and will actually quit until it encounters a "Exit Sub".
When the normal "End Sub" at the primary level is encountered,
it will then also close Excel. But say if the workbook is somehow
closed before reaching the "Exit Sub", "End" or "End Sub" line, then
Excel will not close.

Solution is to create a Public variable called ToQuitNow
with initial False value
and change it to True where you want Excel to quit.
and test right after to see if it is true, then return to previous Sub level
by "Exit Sub" or "End" to quit right away,
and do the same at every subrountine level where
it is expected to return from the deeper subroutine.
When it gets back to the primary level,
then a final "Exit Sub" will actually terminates Excel.
If you do not want Excel to ask for saving changes made,
add line "ThisWorkbook.Saved = True" right after Application.Quit,
or before the final "Exit Sub" at the Primary level
and Excel will quit without saving.

Try the following test below, just run "Test"

```
Public ToQuitNow As Boolean

Sub Test()

ToQuitNow = False ' initialize with False value
Call SecondSub
MsgBox ("Primary level here. Back from SecondSub")
If ToQuitNow = True Then
    Exit Sub 'will actually quit Excel now if True
End If
MsgBox ("This line will not run if ToQuitNow is True")
End Sub

Sub SecondSub()

MsgBox ("SecondSub here")
Call ThirdSub
MsgBox ("SecondSub here. Back from ThirdSub")
If ToQuitNow = True Then
    Exit Sub ' will return to Main level if True
End If
MsgBox ("This line from SecondSub will not run if ToQuitNow is True")
End Sub

Sub ThirdSub()

MsgBox ("ThirdSub here")
Call FourthSub
MsgBox ("ThirdSub here. Back from FourthSub")
If ToQuitNow = True Then
    Exit Sub ' will return to SecondSub if True
End If
MsgBox ("This line from ThirdSub will not run if ToQuitNow is True")
End Sub

Sub FourthSub()

MsgBox ("FourthSub here")
Application.Quit
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True ' Excel will think changes already saved _
and will quit without saving
ToQuitNow = True ' activate Quit
If ToQuitNow = True Then
    MsgBox ("Quit command executed in FourthSub")
    Exit Sub ' will return to ThirdSub if True
    'Can also put in End in above line to quit right away

End If
MsgBox ("This line from FourthSub will not run if ToQuitNow is True.")
End Sub
```

Comment: "When Application.Quit is encountered in a subroutine, it will only stay in memory and continue to run lines under it and will actually quit until it encounters a "Exit Sub". " I did not know this. Excellent to have learned that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

remove the `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` from the routine.

from the help for `Application.Quit Method`:

> If unsaved workbooks are open when you use this method, Microsoft Excel displays a dialog box asking whether you want to save the changes. You can prevent this by saving all workbooks before using the **Quit** method or by setting the *DisplayAlerts* property to **False**. When this property is **False**, Microsoft Excel doesn’t display the dialog box when you quit with unsaved workbooks; it quits without saving them.

This will avoid any (possibly hidden) prompts from stopping excel from closing completely

Comment: my excel will open in read only as it is a public file. 
So i dont want any prompt ! I have ur suggesstion but same result. Probably this is not my answer

Answer (score 1):

I did not try it, but maybe this will help:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/606195-vba-application-quit-not-working-me-completly-why.html

According to Norie you might not have anymore workbooks open, therefore Application.Quit will never be executed.

AlphaFrog therefore suggests this:

> ```
> Application.DisplayAlerts = False
>
> If Application.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
>
>     Application.Quit
>
> Else
>
>     ActiveWorkbook.Close
>
> End If
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The window does not close because you are using personal.xlsb. Cut Personal.xlsb and paste in another location.

Instead of Personal.xlsb create and work on modules. It's a better option.

Answer (score 0):

"ThisWorkbook.Saved = True" after "Application.Quit" works on Excel 2016

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.Quit
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using the following code closed excel cleanly:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.Quit
```

This will allow excel to cleanly close without keeping a "ghost" window open.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:  (Office 365)

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

ThisWorkbook.Save

Application.Quit
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using this

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False     
Application.Quit
```

But berfor this word don't use this

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close
ThisWorkbook.Close
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a strange one, hopefully someone will find this answer useful.  I ran into something very similar using Excel 2010 (14.0).  I stumbled to my answer through experimentation.  This is bad answer for general purpose.

For whatever reason Application.Quit fails silently if the option AccessVBOM is not enabled.  It is not enabled out of the box and can be set/unset by your network admin by windows policy.

You can find this option in the GUI by traversing "Excel Options" -> "Trust Center" -> "Trust Center Settings" -> "Macro Settings" -> "Trust access to the VBA project object model".  Or [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21306593/4995043).

[image: AccessVBOM]
.

Since we all love code, in this example we are running Excel from C# interop and calling the quit function.

```cs
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Marshal = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal;

Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
app.Visible = false;
app.DisplayAlerts = false;

// this will hang if AccessVBOM is not enabled
app.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
```

Comment: This setting has **nothing** to do with the `Application.Quit()` method in VBA, it is purely to enable access to the VBIDE and VBProject object models. **This is potentially dangerous if enabled for no good reason** and that's why it is _deliberately_ hidden within the settings dialog. Also the question has nothing to do with C#.NET and/or Office interop

Answer (score -1):

Have passed MacroName from bat file and tried the below code its working. But one thing I observed is if we are closing the workbook(ActiveWorkbook.Close) before Application.Quit then it is not working.

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()
Dim strMacroName As String
strMacroName = 
VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("process").Item("MacroName")
If strMacroName <> "" Then Run strMacroName
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
If strMacroName <> "" Then Application.Quit
End Sub

Sub Button1_Click()
MsgBox ("done")
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your sheets do not have any external link references, especially broken links.

I struggled with this problem for more than a week, rewriting and commenting out lots of code to try to isolate the problem. I finally did a review of all table and external sheet references in my workbook this morning. I removed all unnecessary links and broken references and the workbook now closes without hanging in memory.