# How to add VBA code to Excel worksheet using PowerShell?

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I need to include a `Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick (ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)` in my Sheet(1).

I'm able to open and write in cells.

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$worksheet = $workbook.WorkSheets.item(1)
$worksheet.range("c1","g6").value = "str"
...
$workbook.SaveAs($xlFlie, 50)
$Excel.Application.Quit()
```

How do I put the VBA code in the sheet (rather than in a VBA module)?

I tried this:

```
$xlmodule = $workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add()
$xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString($code)
```

I got this error:

> Can not call a method in an expression Null.
>   Au caractère .\Build-ADGrpsMembers2Excel.ps1:273 : 5
>   +     $xlmodule = $workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (:) [], RuntimeException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I need to change VBA option to

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\$($excel.Version)\excel\Security" -Name AccessVBOM -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\$($excel.Version)\excel\Security" -Name VBAWarnings -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null
```

[image]

my working code is :

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\$($excel.Version)\excel\Security" -Name AccessVBOM -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\$($excel.Version)\excel\Security" -Name VBAWarnings -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
$worksheet=$workbook.WorkSheets.item(1)

$excel.Visible=$true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $true
$excel.ScreenUpdating = $true

#$worksheet.range("c1","f6").ColumnWidth = 4
#$worksheet.range("c1","f6").Orientation = 90

$xlmodule = $workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.item('feuil1')
$code = @"
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
End Sub
"@

$xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString($code)

$saveName = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath('desktop'))\Export-Excel ($( ((Get-Date -Format u ) -replace ":", ".") -replace "Z", '' ) ).xlsb"

# savegarde du fichier
$workbook.SaveAs($saveName, 50)

Write-Verbose "Closing $($WorkSheetName)"
$Excel.Workbooks.Close()
Write-Verbose "Exit Excel"
$Excel.Application.Quit
```

Comment: don't you need 52 instead of 50 for $workbook.SaveAs($saveName, 50)  according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat?view=excel-pia

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me a lot but I had to add another module, so I did something like this

```
$workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1) 
$workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(2) 
$workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)
```

1 is for module, 2 is for userform, 3 is for class

to grab just-added module it will be in the last place in the array of Components

```
$arrayOfComponents = @($workbook.VBProject.VBComponents)
$justAddedModule = $arrayOfComponents[$arrayOfComponents.Length-1]
```

so it looks something like this

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$vbaProject = new-object -ComObject VB
$FilePath = "c:\temp\excel.xlsm"
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\$($excel.Version)\excel\Security" -Name AccessVBOM -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\$($excel.Version)\excel\Security" -Name VBAWarnings -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add($FilePath)
# Add(1) za dodavanje modula
#$workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)

$xlmodule = $workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.item('Module1')


$code = @"
Sub test()
'
End Sub
"@
$xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString($code)
$workbook.SaveAs($FilePath,52)
$excel.Workbooks.Close() 
$excel.Application.Quit()
```