# VBA Excel File staying open in the background

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am currently using a module on Microsoft Access to Open an Excel file and paste the results into an email. The module is working properly, but the Excel file is remaining open in the background. This is causing an issue when I try to run the same module using the same file.

The Excel file I am using also automatically updates a date field, so I also need the close call to save the file beforehand, or ignore the save changes pop-up.

```
Public Function emailPaste(exFile As String, exSheet As String, exRange As String, _
EmailSubject As String, To_Field As String, Optional CC_Field As String)

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim ApXL As Object

Set ApXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ApXL.Workbooks.Open (exFile)


Set rng = Nothing
' Only send the visible cells in the selection.

Set rng = Sheets(exSheet).Range(exRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'If rng Is Nothing Then
    'MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    'Exit Sub
'End If

With ApXL.Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Call OpenOutlook
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


With OutMail
    .To = To_Field
    .CC = CC_Field
    .Subject = EmailSubject
    .HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:12pt;font-family:Calibri> The report: " & EmailSubject & " " & _
"is pasted below. <br><br> Please review it and contact me if there are any issues.<br><br> " _
& RangetoHTML(rng) & ""
    ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
    ' display the e-mail message.
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With ApXL.Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

ApXL.Quit

Set ApXL = Nothing
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Function
```

How can I add at the end the code needed to save the excel file and close it without any user intervention?

Comment: remove that `On Error GoTo 0`. Close the Workbook first, without saving.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24591967/2727437

Comment: I tried just closing the workbook, but the save changes pop-up appears. I tired to save it first but i get an error every time i run it. The code I'm using to save it is: ApXL.Workbooks.Save

Answer (score 0):

You must be very strict in opening the Excel objects and closing them in reverse order - as done in this example:

```
Public Sub RenameWorkSheet()

    Dim xls     As Excel.Application
    Dim wkb     As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks     As Excel.Worksheet

    Set xls = New Excel.Application
    Set wkb = xls.Workbooks.Open("c:\test\workbook1.xlsx")
    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets(1)

    wks.Name = "My New Name"
    wkb.Close True

    Set wks = Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing

    xls.Quit

    Set xls = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: So I did what you suggested, and it seemed to be working, but shutting down showed me windows was still running the excel file in the background

Comment: `Dim ApXL As Excel.Application
 Dim WbXL As Excel.Workbook
    
    Set ApXL = New Excel.Application
    Set WbXL = ApXL.Workbooks.Open(exFile)
    
    
    Set rng = Nothing
    ' Only send the visible cells in the selection.
    
    Set rng = WbXL.Sheets(exSheet).Range(exRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    End With
    ApXL.DisplayAlerts = False
    WbXL.Save
    WbXL.Close
    Set WbXL = Nothing
    ApXL.DisplayAlerts = True  
    ApXL.Quit
    Set ApXL = Nothing
End Function`

Comment: Well. You opened `rng` without using a/the worksheet object, and without setting `rng = Nothing` before exiting. That will leave the Excel instance open. So try again: _You must be very strict in opening the Excel objects and closing them in reverse order._

Answer (score 0):

1. You should try to tell the Application, that the Worksheet is saved
   as it is.
2. Then Close the Worksheet
3. Then try to Close the Application.

something like this:

```
exFile.Sheets(exSheet).Saved = True
exFile.Sheets(exSheet).Close
ApXL.Quit
```

Or tell, that it doesn't have to save on closing...:

```
exFile.Sheets(exSheet).Close False
ApXL.Quit
```

I'd also propose, that you should store a direct reference to the Sheet and not implicitly calling the sheet via the active window...

Something like

```
dim wsh as Worksheet
set wsh = exFile.Sheets(exSheet)
```

then you can work with the variable wsh... more comfortable